# Lorentz transformation of electromagnetic field tensor

Tags: mathematical-physics, tensors

I need to calculate:

$f^{\mu'\nu'}=L^{\mu}_{\kappa}L^\nu_\lambda f^{\kappa\lambda}$

Where $L^\nu_\lambda$ is the usual Lorentz transformation matrix I thought that I just needed to do some normal matrix multiplications as the RHS terms are 4x4 matrices but the result does not agree with the solution I was given. Is there something else I need to consider In multip

Comment: would you mind to say us what exactly is different? Furthermore which kind of LT do we consider, or some special cases like 1-D Boost, Rotation around one axis etc.? Has the Faraday Tensor all entry or transform we from for example a rest frame?

Comment: I'm wondering if you've left something out since you have primed indices on the left side of the equation for $\mu$ and $\nu$ but not on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to compute in matrix form is
$$F' = \Lambda F\Lambda^T$$
You can see that this is the case by a correct ordering of the indices in the expression you have given in the question.